# PyQt5 Button click doesn't change the label text

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I started learning PyQt5 and wrote the following simple code. But, when `sum` button is being clicked then nothing happens even though I already added the click event.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text_b = QLabel('Second Number', self)
        self.text_a = QLabel('First Number', self)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 750, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Project Window')

        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        enter_button = QPushButton('Sum', self)
        self.text_a.move(50, 50)
        self.text_b.move(200, 50)
        enter_button.move(125, 180)
        enter_button.clicked.connect(self.enter_func)
        self.show()

    def enter_func(self):
        self.text_a.setText('Clicked First Number')


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PyCharm highlights the following warning

> Unresolved attribute reference 'connect' for class 'pyqtBoundSignal'

Comment: This works for me. Before Clicking: https://i.gyazo.com/a32402bd8c34db51d7011c7e37754964.png .... After Clicking: https://i.gyazo.com/275f8174720649da6133138f8e88970f.png ... Though it changes to "Clicked First" instead of "Clicked First Number" but it works

Comment: your code is working fine, maybe you have t check your pyqt installation if doesnt work.

Comment: add `self.text_a.repaint()`